# Apache Mina SSHD SFTP server fails to list some directories on Android

Tags: android, ssh, sftp, apache-mina, mina

Using [Apache Mina SSHD](http://mina.apache.org/sshd-project/index.html) I've implemented an SSH and SFTP server in an Android app I'm working on, and I can log in through SSH fine, ls the root directory, cd to 'mnt/sdcard' and ls - all of this is working fine. I can also get su and do whatever else I want.

However when I connect through SFTP I am unable to list the contents of most directories (including '/', '/mnt/sdcard'). I can, however, list the contents of '/mnt/sdcard/Download' - as well as download and upload to and from that directory.

It seems that certain files are halting the directory listing in it's tracks - for example, in '/mnt/sdcard' it seems that 'TWRP' is the cause of the problem. Here's what I get in WinSCP:

> General failure (server should provide error description).
>
> Error code: 4
> Error message from server: /mnt/sdcard/TWRP

Here's what I get from FileZilla (much less descriptive):

> Command:  cd "/mnt/sdcard" Response:  New directory is: "/mnt/sdcard"
>
> Command:  ls Status:  Listing directory /mnt/sdcard
>
> Error: Reading directory .: failure Status:    Directory listing successful

When trying to list the directories in '/' in WinSCP:

> General failure (server should provide error description).
>
> Error code: 4
> Error message from server: /charger

I've implemented a custom FileSystemFactory in order to default incoming SFTP connections to '/mnt/sdcard/Download', but I would like to be able to SFTP to any directory (I don't mind using su if needed)

Here's the relevant code to set up the Android SSH/SFTP server and set the custom FileSystemFactory:

```
//Initialize the server:
final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(server_service.class);
final SshServer sshd = SshServer.setUpDefaultServer();
final SimplePasswordAuthenticator passwordAuth = new SimplePasswordAuthenticator();
final SimplePublicKeyAuthenticator publicKeyAuth = new SimplePublicKeyAuthenticator();

passwordAuth.setUser(username_string);
passwordAuth.setPassword(password_string);
sshd.setPort(port);
sshd.setKeyPairProvider(new SimpleGeneratorHostKeyProvider(server_info.getAppContext().getFilesDir().getPath() + "/key.ser"));
sshd.setShellFactory(new PseudoTerminalFactory("/system/bin/sh", "-i"));
sshd.setPasswordAuthenticator(passwordAuth);
sshd.setPublickeyAuthenticator(publicKeyAuth);
sshd.setSubsystemFactories(Arrays.<NamedFactory<Command>>asList(new SftpSubsystem.Factory()));
sshd.setFileSystemFactory(getModifiedNativeFileSystemFactory());

try {
    sshd.start();
    Log.i("SUCCESS: Server listening on port",Integer.toString(port));
    server_info.sshd = sshd;
    server_info.log = log;
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Log.e("FAILURE: Server start failed", ex.toString());
    ex.printStackTrace();
}


}

//Custom FileSystemFactory to change initial root directory on SFTP connection
NativeFileSystemFactory getModifiedNativeFileSystemFactory() {
    return new NativeFileSystemFactory() {

    @Override
    public FileSystemView createFileSystemView(Session session) {
        String userName = getUsername(session);
        NativeFileSystemView nfsv = new ModifiedNativeFileSystemView(
                userName, isCaseInsensitive());
        Log.d("Creating a modified NativeFileSystemView for user", nfsv.getUserName());
        return nfsv;
    }

};
}
//Hook for testing without valid session
String getUsername(Session session) {
    return session.getUsername();
}
//Class to return the altered FileSystemView with changed initial directory
class ModifiedNativeFileSystemView extends NativeFileSystemView {
    String modifiedRootDir;

public ModifiedNativeFileSystemView(String userName,boolean caseInsensitive) {
    super(userName, caseInsensitive);
    modifiedRootDir = System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + TARGET_DIR_NAME;
    Log.d("Modified NativeFileSystemView created with root directory", modifiedRootDir);
}

@Override
public SshFile getFile(String file) {
    return getFile(modifiedRootDir, file);
}
}
```

**EDIT: Fixed SD card access with "su restorecon -FR /data/media/0".**  It turns out that the TWRP folder had bad permissions after my upgrade to Lollipop (even with "su ls -l" it wouldn't return the permissions, just said access denied).  After fixing those permissions, I am able to list the sdcard directories with SFTP just fine.
However, I'm still unable to list the root directories ('/') with SFTP, but there are no problems doing it with "su ls -l" while SSH'd in (it does not work without su). I don't believe it to be the same issue - I think it's just that my SFTP access is not su.
Can anyone tell me how would I make SFTP run as su?

Comment: which version of sshd do you use? When I tried it I get a lot of crashes as mina uses java.nio  in a lot of places and this is not available on Android